# Defining a variable inside a function to reference it in the function

Tags: functions

I am trying to define a variable and use it inside a function. However, I am having troubles calling the variable. For instance, I define the function

```
interSpecialCycle[permutation_]:=PermutationCycles[permutation][[1]][[1]]
```

and I want to assign that function to a variable of the form

```
list1 = SpecialCycle = interSpecialCycle[permutation]
```

I want to use these variables in different functions I want to write, but when I call list1 nothing happens.

Is there a way to do this in mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
interSpecialCycle[permutation_] := 
 PermutationCycles[permutation][[1]][[1]]
myperm = {1, 4, 2, 5, 3}
list1 = SpecialCycle = interSpecialCycle[myperm]
```

But `list1` will not be callable, so I don't know what you mean by that: `interSpecialCycle[myperm]` returns a list.  Are you saying that you currently call it several times with the *same* argument?  Then just store the result in a variable.  It sound like you want that variable to be local to your larger function.  If that's the case, use `Module`:

```
myfunc[input_List]:=Module[{list1=interSpecialCycle[input]},
  <function body referring to list1>]
```

Comment: So I am writing a big function and I will call several times SpecialCycle and so on, but the problem with list1 = SpecialCycle = interSpecialCycle[myperm] is that I need to change myperm everytime I use a different list and I am trying to do it a bit more automatic by just changing the list once in the whole program.

Comment: @user41116 This is still unclear. `interSpecialCycle[myperm]` returns a list.  Are you saying that you currently call it several times with the *same* argument?  Then just store the result in a variable -- presumably a variable that is local to your large function.  I'll add an example.